# jQuery onclick toggle class name

Tags: jquery

Using jQuery, how do I toggle classA to classB on click going from:

```
<a class="switch" href="#">Switch</a>
<div class="classA"></div>


$('.switch').on('click', function(e){
    $('.classA').removeClass('classA').addClass('classB');
    e.preventDefault();
};
```

How do I toggle the class, instead of just replacing it like I'm doing here?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

jQuery has a [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) function:

```
<button class="switch">Click me</button>

<div class="text-block collapsed pressed">some text</div>

<script>    
    $('.switch').on('click', function(e) {
      $('.text-block').toggleClass("collapsed pressed"); //you can list several class names 
      e.preventDefault();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 30):

[you can use](https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) `toggleClass()`  to toggle class it is really handy.

case:1

```
<div id='mydiv' class="class1"></div>

$('#mydiv').toggleClass('class1 class2');

output: <div id='mydiv' class="class2"></div>
```

case:2

```
<div id='mydiv' class="class2"></div>

$('#mydiv').toggleClass('class1 class2');

output: <div id='mydiv' class="class1"></div>
```

case:3

```
<div id='mydiv' class="class1 class2 class3"></div>

$('#mydiv').toggleClass('class1 class2');

output: <div id='mydiv' class="class3"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It can even be made dependent to another attribute changes. like this:

```js
$('.classA').toggleClass('classB', $('input').prop('disabled'));
```

In this case, `classB` are added each time the input is `disabled`