# Show/hide li icon when clicked on with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Building my first website, so please be patient with me. I'm trying to hide/show list item icon when clicked on the particular li, I know how to go around this using CSS3, but I would like to do use jQuery. Any tips?

Here is my html code:

```
<ul id="nav" class="grid_1 push_3"> 
    <li class="icon"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="icon"><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
    <li class="icon"><a href="#">Recipies</a></li>
    <li class="icon"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

and my CSS:

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin-top:2%;
}

ul li{
    font-family: 'cheveuxdangemedium', Georgia, Serif;
    font-size: 1em;
}

ul li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #bec4b8;
    text-align: left;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-left: -0.4em;
}

li.icon {
    list-style-image: url("../images/greanleaf.png");
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: -0.1em;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery onclick toggle class name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15627955/jquery-onclick-toggle-class-name)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears as though you're asking how to toggle the `icon` class.

```
$('#nav li').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('icon').siblings('li').removeClass('icon');
});
```

- http://api.jquery.com/click
- http://api.jquery.com/addClass
- http://api.jquery.com/siblings

You'll need to implement this in a `<script>` tag after your HTML markup, or you'll need to wrap it in a `document.ready` function to run it when the markup has been rendered.

In the future, please do make an effort before asking and show us what's not working. The jQuery docs are very easy to follow.

Comment: Thank you, but it's not exactly what I'm looking for. Icon to be shown for the active link only, hide the rest. Should work like a:active link state in CSS.

Comment: Ok. You should make that more clear in your question. Answer updated to handle sibling elements as well.

Comment: You are a lifesaver, isherwood. Great tips and links. Highly appreciated! Works perfectly fine. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#nav li').on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('icon')
});
```

Comment: thank you, but it's not exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with native HTML5. This isn't yet supported in all major browsers, but there are polyfills that can implant that functionality into browsers that don't yet support it.

```
<details>
  <summary>Click here</summary>
  <p>Now this shows.</p>
</details>
```

Comment: thanks for the info, highly appreciated. I managed to make it work with jQuery in the meanwhile.