# JQuery - Add and remove class on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
$('.toggle-button').on('click', function() {
    $('body').addClass('changeCursor');
  });

  $('.toggle-button.toggle-active').on('click', function() {
    $('body').removeClass('changeCursor');
  });
```

Hey guys I need to add class on body and should remove when again click on it. I have attached my code above. But it's not working please go through for more clarity. Thanks :)

Comment: What does not working mean in this context? What error are you getting? Could you post your HTML as well?

Comment: `$('.toggle-button.toggle-active').on(…)` - does your toggle button actually have the class `toggle-active` at the moment this line is executed …? Presumably not. Please go read [mcve] and edit your question accordingly, so we don’t have to guess.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery onclick toggle class name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15627955/jquery-onclick-toggle-class-name)

Answer (score 7):

**You can use** `toggleClass()`

Example:

```
$('.toggle-button').on('click', function() {
    $('body').toggleClass('changeCursor');
});
```

Docs: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: No problem, happy coding!

Comment: Please mark this as the answer if you found it worked for you.

Answer (score -1):

Check if your body has the class, if not add it, else remove it.

```
$('.toggle-button').on('click', function() {
    if($('body').hasClass('changeCursor')) {
        $('body').removeClass('changeCursor');
    } else {
        $('body').addClass('changeCursor');
    }
});
```

Comment: this is more or less the functionality behind `.toggleClass` - thus, no need for checking with `.hasClass`