# Apply certain .class on JavaScript button AND avoid misalignment of the text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/sb681nyf/1/) is the JSFiddle with the code.
**Goal:** button click should apply `.blur_filter_off` class to `span id="hint"` **only**. The whole text should stay as it is, i.e. in **1** line.
**Current problems:** 1) button click deactivates `display:none` property instead of applying `.blur_filter_off` class. 2) Text splits into **2** lines on button click.
**Additional info:** not sure `display:none` is needed *in general*, as the idea is the following: `span id="hint"` is *initially* blurred via `blur_filter_on` class and becomes UNblurred on button click via `blur_filter_off` class. Maybe there's a way to do so without implementing `display:none` property at all.

```js
function showHint(id1) {

  var x = document.getElementById(id1).style;

  x.display = (x.display != "block") ? "block" : "none";

}
```

```css
.example {
  color: #1f2c60;
  font-size: calc(0.7em + 2.3vw);
}

.blur_filter_on {
  filter: blur(0.35em);
}

.blur_filter_off {
  animation-name: blur_decrease;
  animation-timing-function: ease;
  animation-duration: 1s;
}

@keyframes blur_decrease {
  from {
    filter: blur(0.35em);
  }
  to {
    filter: blur(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="example"><span class="blur_filter_on"><span id="hint">This is</span> the sentence i use as an</span> example.</span>
</div>

<a class=hint href="#" onclick="showHint('hint')">BUTTON</a>
```

Comment: I don't see you're using `blur_filter_off` any where.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery onclick toggle class name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15627955/jquery-onclick-toggle-class-name)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution that would work to meet the Goal you specified. I am using plain javascript here, you can also use jQuery to achieve this. It required tweaking HTML and CSS as well.

The updated working fiddle is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cv84k51x/1/)

```js
function showHint(id1) {
  var x = document.getElementById(id1);
  var blurOffClass = "blur_filter_off";
  
  if (!x.classList.contains(blurOffClass)) {
     x.classList.add(blurOffClass);
  }
}
```

```css
.example {
  color: #1f2c60;
  font-size: calc(0.7em + 2.3vw);
}

.blur_filter_on > * {
  filter: blur(0.35em);
}

.blur_filter_off {
  animation-name: blur_decrease;
  animation-timing-function: ease;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  filter: blur(0);
}

@keyframes blur_decrease {
from { filter: blur(0.35em); }
to { filter: blur(0); }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="example">
    <span class="blur_filter_on">
        <span id="hint">This is</span>
        <span>the sentence i use as an</span>
    </span>
    example.
  </span>
</div>

<a class=hint href="#" onclick="showHint('hint')">BUTTON</a>
```

Comment: Thank you Ashish, this is exactly what was needed! I tried to modify your code with the _second_ span id added, but it didn't work. Could you please kindly have a look? Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/r5jedcqx/1/

Comment: @HexenSage I am happy, it was helpful. :)
I took a look at the provided fiddle. Here is the fiddle that works: https://jsfiddle.net/mc5wjfru/1/. I have added comments about what's updated.

Comment: Amazing, Ashish! Thank you for comments too. Sending virtual sunrays to your karma, dude. :-)

Comment: Hi, Ashish, i'm really VERY sorry to disturb you again on the same matter, but could you please kindly have a look at this Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zjg84sq3/  This is the _final_ layout (with a bit of design added), and the blur_filter_off class is not applied to <span id="hint_ru"> and <span id="hint_en"> on button click for some reason. :-( Though looks like i did everything like you've recommended... I'm really SORRY to take your time, but need your help badly.. Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: no worries man. here is the working fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/fovc1qw8/1/. I have added comments to the styles that required to be changed to achieve the final effect. look for `Comment:` in css inside the fiddle. I hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH Ashish, comments were very helpful - appreciate that. You're the best, dude! :)