# Add additional class click

Tags: javascript, css

I get this class `"ind open1"` for example  and I want to add an additional class to the `panel` class for exactly those blocks that have the class ""

for example , i click  `ind open0` and the `panel` add class `panel current` but if class has then remove

```
<div class="ind open0" onclick="someFunction(this)">
   <div class="panel"></div>
</div>
<div class="ind open0" onclick="someFunction(this)">
   <div class="panel"></div>
</div>
<div class="ind open1" onclick="someFunction(this)">
   <div class="panel"></div>
</div>
<div class="ind open1" onclick="someFunction(this)">
   <div class="panel"></div>
</div>
<div class="ind open2" onclick="someFunction(this)">
   <div class="panel"></div>
</div>
<div class="ind open2" onclick="someFunction(this)">
   <div class="panel"></div>
</div>

function someFunction(obj) {
        alert($(obj).attr('class'));  //ind open1
    }
```

I want this result if i click `ind open0` class

```
 <div class="ind open0" onclick="someFunction(this)">
       <div class="panel current"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="ind open0" onclick="someFunction(this)">
       <div class="panel current"></div>
    </div>


   <div class="ind open1" onclick="someFunction(this)">
   <div class="panel"></div>
</div>
<div class="ind open1" onclick="someFunction(this)">
   <div class="panel"></div>
</div>
<div class="ind open2" onclick="someFunction(this)">
   <div class="panel"></div>
</div>
<div class="ind open2" onclick="someFunction(this)">
   <div class="panel"></div>
</div>
```

if i click `ind open1` class

```
<div class="ind open0" onclick="someFunction(this)">
   <div class="panel"></div>
</div>
<div class="ind open0" onclick="someFunction(this)">
   <div class="panel"></div>
</div>
enter code here
<div class="ind open1" onclick="someFunction(this)">
       <div class="panel current"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="ind open1" onclick="someFunction(this)">
       <div class="panel current"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="ind open2" onclick="someFunction(this)">
   <div class="panel"></div>
</div>
<div class="ind open2" onclick="someFunction(this)">
   <div class="panel"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by: but if class has then remove?

Comment: if the class "current" is, then it must be deleted

Comment: Are you looking for this => `$(".panel").toggleClass("current");`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery onclick toggle class name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15627955/jquery-onclick-toggle-class-name)

Comment: @KaranSingh not really. I need one more class to be added by clicking on `open0` to the `panel` class, for example, and this should happen in all `open0` containers

Comment: @NikitaKurilovic What do you mean by "one more class"?

Comment: I edit question

Comment: @NikitaKurilovic So you want to toggle the `current` class for all the panels?

Comment: @hev1  Yes . I want to toggle the `current` class for all the panels for example if i click `ind open0`

Comment: @hev1 Thank you for your efforts :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this codepen:

https://codepen.io/CrowlsYung/pen/f4d8505f7b6e9cdf98f29118ba900f94?editors=1111

#### HTML

```
<div class="ind open0" onclick="someFunction(event)">
   <div class="panel">abc</div>
</div>
<div class="ind open0" onclick="someFunction(event)">
   <div class="panel">def</div>
</div>
<div class="ind open1" onclick="someFunction(event)">
   <div class="panel">ghi</div>
</div>
<div class="ind open1" onclick="someFunction(event)">
   <div class="panel">jkl</div>
</div>
<div class="ind open2" onclick="someFunction(event)">
   <div class="panel">mno</div>
</div>
<div class="ind open2" onclick="someFunction(event)">
   <div class="panel">pqr</div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
.current{
  background-color: red;
  height:100px;
}
```

#### JS

```
function someFunction(event){
 let classList = event.currentTarget.classList.toString();
 let targetClass = classList.toString().slice(classList.indexOf('open'));
  
  let toOpen = document.getElementsByClassName(targetClass);
  for(let el of toOpen){
    let childPanels = el.querySelectorAll('.panel');
    childPanels.forEach(child => {
      child.classList.toggle('current')
    })
   }
}
```

Comment: not quite right ... if I clicked on `open0` then the second one where open0 the `panel` should have an additional class. there are two classes open0 therefore, both "panels" should have an additional class, and in your example this happens only for one

Comment: I updated the codepen!  https://codepen.io/CrowlsYung/pen/f4d8505f7b6e9cdf98f29118ba900f94?editors=1111

this should work : 0